# NPE View.getVisibility()

Tags: android

I have an application that has sent me two of the exact same exception stacktraces from two different users using Galaxy S8+ on Android 7.0

The stacktrace in it's entirety makes no references to any specific part of my own code, so I really have no idea where it's coming from within the app.

Does anyone recognize this stacktrace and what could possibly be causing it?

edit: I know what a NPE is and I know how to fix it, but this stacktrace does not show me what part of the app is causing the NPE.  the stacktrace is sent to me via email when a user has a crash of any kind, 99% of the time the stacktrace contains a clear 'caused by' line that i can see where in the app caused the exception, but these stacktrace below do not.

```
Stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:275)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:935)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2697)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2413)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7189)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Stacktraces usually have a "Caused by" line which points to the line in your code that triggered it.

Comment: Put your code and more log here

Comment: Does your app have visible adverts?

Comment: it's a private app, no adverts, and i know what a nullpointerexception is and how to fix it.. i just don't know where in the code it's getting a npe because the stacktrace is not showing me where its coming from. usually it will tell me what caused the npe but this is very vague above